Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "__mh_execute_header" - Unity as a library embedding issue with Xcode 16 beta
Tried Xcode 16.1 beta today but project is not able to build because of the below error:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__mh_execute_header"

I am using unity as a lib in iOS project. And issue is with unity integration
 let machineHeader = UnsafeMutablePointer<MachHeader>.allocate(capacity: 1)
 machineHeader.pointee = _mh_execute_header
 ufw!.setExecuteHeader(machineHeader)

Did some research and found this solution by Apple DTS
Apple Forums
But not able to figure out how to solve. Any help is appreciated.

Fixed this issue using below code:
let machineHeader = #dsohandle.assumingMemoryBound(to: MachHeader.self)
ufw!.setExecuteHeader(machineHeader)

Explanation:
While checking the answer from support team, I came across below line:

In Swift you can use #dsohandle to get the start of the Mach-O image regardless of the image type, so this problem goes away. Well, you’ll need to combine that with an unsafeBitCast(_:to:).

#dsohandle: This is a special Swift literal that gives you a handle to the dynamic shared object (DSO) that contains the current code. In other words, it provides access to the starting address of the Mach-O image (the binary that represents the executable or library).
So replacing the direct reference to _mh_execute_header with a reference that uses #dsohandle help to solve the compilation error.
Happy coding.

I am having a similar issue (at least the same build error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78992333/new-build-error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-16)
I tried adding this line of code, and no luck. Can you provide more context how you got unity to build as a library in XCode16, maybe I'm missing other configuration? That question has a bounty if you want to help by placing an answer there.
