New build error after upgrading to XCode 16
I have a iOS project that links in unity as a library. Everything built fine until today after upgrading to XCode16. Now my project cannot build with the below error
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__mh_execute_header", referenced from:
      Builder.UnityService.(loadUnityFramework in _C1B4CF2F667E7F31717AD3C6734A533B)() -> __C.UnityFramework? in UnityService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried upgrading to the lastest unity version to build, and same error. I'm unsure exactly how to debug this, anybody else able to build unity as a library in XCode16, what other debug steps can I take here?

I have confirmed a clean unity project built in the same way does work without the error, so the problem appears to be a dependency my unity project has, but given the vagueness of the error, I don't have any clues on where to start here.
edit: I take it back, even an empty project seems to fail. No idea how I got it to work the other day, but I've been slowly removing dependencies, then opened a blank project to check it's build settings, and even an empty project compiling against iOS is giving me the same compiler error.
I've upgraded to unity 6 and XCode 16.1, and am still getting the same error trying to build a blank unity project as a library. I've added a screenshot of the build logs, not sure if there's more details I can dig from elsewhere.


What versions of Unity and XCode were you originally using?

Everything works on the latest XCode 15, the version of unity doesn't seem to have any relevance. Was just upgrading to see if it was a known issue that was solved.

I see this question as well, may have relevance, but the solution doesn't seem to solve the build error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932936/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-mh-execute-header-unity-as-a-lib

Are you using Cocoapods by any chance? I remember reading that many people use that option for working with libaries in Unity for IOS.

Actually I realized there was a routine I was using I forgot about that needed the update, the answer to the other question does indeed fix it for me. I'll add an answer.

Ok cool. The only other things Ive found that might help was to update/reinstall Cocoapods or double check the connection between both Unity and XCode.

I have found the answer thanks to this question: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "__mh_execute_header" - Unity as a library embedding issue with Xcode 16 beta
I had a routine I had written and forgot about that looked like this:
private func loadUnityFramework() -> UnityFramework? {
    let bundlePath: String = Bundle.main.bundlePath + frameworkPath

    let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath)
    if bundle?.isLoaded == false {
        bundle?.load()
    }

    let ufw = bundle?.principalClass?.getInstance()
    if ufw?.appController() == nil {
        let machineHeader = UnsafeMutablePointer<MachHeader>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        machineHeader.pointee = _mh_execute_header

        ufw?.setExecuteHeader(machineHeader)
    }
    return ufw
}

The machine header portion needs to be updated in XCode 16 to the following:
private func loadUnityFramework() -> UnityFramework? {
    let bundlePath: String = Bundle.main.bundlePath + frameworkPath

    let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath)
    if bundle?.isLoaded == false {
        bundle?.load()
    }

    let ufw = bundle?.principalClass?.getInstance()
    if ufw?.appController() == nil {
        let machineHeader = #dsohandle.assumingMemoryBound(to: MachHeader.self)

        ufw?.setExecuteHeader(machineHeader)
    }
    return ufw
}

This solves the issue for me.
